# Вывести элемент массива

Tags: php

Формирую массив в цикле след. образом:

```
$preGroup = array();
while ($table = $db->fetch_assoc()) {
    $preGroup[] = array("param" => $table['param'], "id" => $table['id'], "type" => $table['type']);
}
```

Хочу вывести первый элемент массива:

```
echo $preGroup[0];
```

Получаю ответ:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in ...
>
> Array

Comment: `var_dump($preGroup[0]);` - и все выведете, как писали выше, `echo` - выводит только строки а не массивы.

Comment: у вас двумерный массив, $preGroup[0]["param"] ...

Answer (score 0):

У вас двухмерный массив, соответственное в $preGroup[0] содержится массив, а не строка, а вы его хотите вывести через echo. Используйте print_r() или var_dump():

```
print_r($preGroup[0]);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$preGroup = array();
    while ($table = $db->fetch_assoc()) {

        foreach ($table as $key => $val) {
            $preGroup[][$key] = $val;
            echo $preGroup [0][$key];
    }
}
```